# SwiftUI scaleEffect Causes Unwanted Position Change

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-animation

*Xcode 12.4 + macOS 11.2.3*

I've put together a really simple SwiftUI project in a Mac app, and I don't understand why `scaleEffect` is behaving this way.

Here's my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var active = false
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      Text("Hi")
        .scaleEffect(active ? 2 : 1)
        .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1).repeatForever())
      Button("Toggle Animation"){
        active.toggle()
      }
    }
    .frame(width:200, height:200)
  }
}
```

My expectation is that the "Hi" text will grow twice as large as soon as I click the button. Instead, the text moves up and down once my view loads. Once I click the button, the text starts getting larger and smaller, but the up and down movement continues.

[image]

Why won't the `Text` stay in its place and simply get larger and smaller?

Comment: Do you have still problem with this issue? or my answer solved the issue?

Comment: You were very helpful, thank you. Your solution didn't quite solve the issue, though. I posted another answer that solved the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: you are welcome, happy you find your answer. but basically my answer is what you posted as answer.

Answer (score 1):

***The way that Animation works in general in iOS or macOS is: that it see and observe the deference in parameters and try to answer them, unless we say ignore some change! or just observe special change like I did in code!***

---

### [image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var toggleAnimation: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            
            Text("Hi")
                .background(Color.red)
                .cornerRadius(2.0)
                .scaleEffect(toggleAnimation ? 2.0 : 1.0)
                .animation(toggleAnimation ? Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1).repeatForever(autoreverses: true) : Animation.easeInOut, value: toggleAnimation)
                

            Button("Toggle Animation") { toggleAnimation.toggle() }
            
        }
        .frame(width:200, height:200)
        .background(Color.black)
 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. That doesn't seem to change anything. The "Hi" text is still oscillating up and down.

Comment: @CliftonLabrum: Sorry I mis understood your question at first place! check the new answer plz.

Comment: Very nice, thank you. There seems to be one last, remaining bug, however. When I click the toggle button and set `active` to `false`, the animation continues. Are you seeing that same problem?

Comment: @CliftonLabrum: That is not an issue! because you **literally** put the code of **.repeatForever()** in animation. If you want stop animation from repeating then you can use this code: **.animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1), value: active)**

Comment: Right, but shouldn't setting `active` to `false` make the animation stop?

Comment: @CliftonLabrum: Good question! No, because as we set and as we asked SwiftUI for animation as **.repeatForever()**, So you want something else! then check new updated code!

Answer (score 0):

There's still an unwanted initial animation with the "Hi" moving into place, but I found a way to start and stop the animation reliably:

```
Text("Hi")
  .scaleEffect(active ? 2 : 1)
  .animation(active ? Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1).repeatForever() : Animation.default)
```

I found this answer which helped: [SwiftUI: Stop an Animation that Repeats Forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59133826/swiftui-stop-an-animation-that-repeats-forever)

With a `.repeatFoever()` animation, you have to pass it an animation when the condition is no longer `true` in order to override the prior, forever-repeating animation.