# Scaled view unexpectedly moving up and down when pushed from navigation view

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a view that should scale in and out, starting immediately when the view is shown and repeating forever. However, I find that it's actually animating up and down as well as scaling [much like in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66717988/swiftui-scaleeffect-causes-unwanted-position-change) when it's pushed from a navigation view:

```
struct PlaceholderView: View {
  @State private var isAnimating = false

  var body: some View {
    Circle()
      .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
      .scaleEffect(self.isAnimating ? 0.8 : 1)
      .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1).repeatForever())
      .onAppear {
        self.isAnimating = true
      }
      .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
      .contentShape(
        Rectangle()
      )
  }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
  @State private var showPlaceholder = false

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      ZStack {
        Button(
          action: {
            showPlaceholder = true
          }, label: {
            Text("Go to placeholder")
          }
        )

        NavigationLink(
          destination: PlaceholderView(),
          isActive: $showPlaceholder
        ) {
          EmptyView()
        }
        .hidden()
      }
    }
    .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
  }
}
```

Why is this and how can I stop this from happening?

**UPDATE:**

Wrapping `self.isAnimating = true` in `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` fixes the issue, but I don't understand why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem, but I wasn't able to reproduce your `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` fix.

Here is how I fixed it:

Animation is made by comparing a *before state* and and *after state* and animating between them.  With an implicit animation, the *before state* is the position of the circle before it is added to the navigation view.  By switching to an *explicit animation* and setting your before state *after* the view appears, the move animation is avoided and you only get the scaling:

Replace `isAnimating` with `scale`.  In `onAppear {}`, first establish the *before* scale of `0.8`, then animate the change to scale `1`:

```
struct PlaceholderView: View {
    // To work correctly, this initial value should be different
    // than the before value set in .onAppear {}.
    @State private var scale = 1.0
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
            .scaleEffect(self.scale)
            .onAppear {
                self.scale = 0.8  // before 
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1).repeatForever()) {
                    self.scale = 1  // after
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            .contentShape(
                Rectangle()
            )
    }
}
```